# iOS check if torch is on

Tags: ios

I would like to check if torch is on. First I open Control Center and then I turn on torch. Next I run my application and perform my torch test. I get AVCaptureDevice like this:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
```

Then I check various properties of device object like:

- torchLevel
- torchActive
- torchMode
- flashActive
- flashMode

But I always get that torch is turn off. Do you need any permission to read this properties or maybe there is another way to check if torch is on?

Comment: I feel like this behavior was not always this way - that it changed as part of some iOS update several years ago.  But to be certain, I wrote some code to iterate through every available AVCaptureDevice using AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession, and checked all the state values with the system flashlight on, as well as off.  Sadly, nothing changed.  See the rest of my note in the "Complete Solution" answer below.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this doesn't technically solve the problem this is KVO code for determining a state change in the torch.  Maybe this could help.  I am trying to solve the same problem but am unable to access any information about the torch that is turned on from the control center.  It seems there should be some other way using KVO or something else to know if the torch is currently active or not.

```
static void * const torchActiveObservationContext = (void*)&torchActiveObservationContext;

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == torchActiveObservationContext) {
        AVCaptureDevice *thisDevice = (AVCaptureDevice*)object;
        NSLog( @"Current torch level: %f", thisDevice.torchActive);
    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

        [videoDevice addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"torchActive" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:torchActiveObservationContext];

        // whatever other initialization code ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

I also tried using torchLevel and torchMode to no avail.  This is a real issue because I want to leave the torch on if it is on already when taking over control of the AVCaptureDevice.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [AVCaptureDevice Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW31), you may also want/need to check if a torch exists in the first place (`hasTorch`), and if it's available/supported (`torchAvailable`).

The property `torchActive` is a read-only Bool, so there shouldn't be any issue w/accessing it, but the docs say:

> A torch must be present on the device and currently available before it can be active.

So maybe you first need to check those 2 properties? Seems silly, but...

Obj-C:

```
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

  if (device.hasTorch && device.torchAvailable)
     NSLog("%ld", device.torchMode) //an NSInteger in an enum 
  }
  else 
  {
      NSLog("Torch not present/available")
  }
```

Swift:

```
let device: AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

if (device.hasTorch && device.torchAvailable){
    println(device.torchMode.rawValue) //print enum Int value
} else {
    println("Torch not present/available")
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't help :(

Answer (score 0):

**Complete Solution: Swift 5.7.2 / Xcode 14.2**

You were probably already checking if the torch was on more or less correctly.  The problem is that the state of the "system" torch (the built-in flashlight that's in Control Center) is not readable by the app – i.e., each app only sees its own state.  So, your app can't see the state of the built-in flashlight app.

Interestingly, if the system flashlight is on, explicitly trying to set the mode to `.off` does nothing.  But, trying to set it to `.on`, causes the torch to turn off briefly, and then back on.  My thought here is that it turning off briefly, is the system flashlight app exiting.  Control then passes to our app, which is trying to turn it on.  This is consistent, because if your app turns on the flashlight, it automatically turns off if the app is force quit.

Regarding general control and checking the current state, I think this solution solves all the issues.

I've got a SwiftUI `ObservableObject` called **`TorchControl`**, but *you don't have to use SwiftUI* to use it.

Here are some example usages:

**Get the current state:**

```swift
// print the current state
let torchControl = torchControl()
print("isTorchOn = \(torchControl.isTorchOn)")
```

**Turn the torch on (if possible):**

```swift
// turn it on
let torchControl = torchControl()
torchControl.isTorchOn = true
```

**Turn the torch off:**

```swift
// turn it off
let torchControl = torchControl()
torchControl.isTorchOn = false
```

Here's the full code which includes a SwiftUI View for testing:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

/// A SwiftUI view for testing `TorchControl`
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var torchControl = TorchControl()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            Text("Torch / Flashlight")
            VStack(spacing: 15) {
                Button("Toggle") { torchControl.isTorchOn.toggle() }
                Button("ON")     { torchControl.isTorchOn = true   }
                Button("OFF")    { torchControl.isTorchOn = false  }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            Text(torchControl.isTorchOn ? "ON" : "OFF").font(.title2).bold()
            Text(torchControl.error?.localizedDescription ?? "").foregroundColor(.red)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
}

/// Manages the torch / flashlight
class TorchControl: ObservableObject {
    /// The latest error, if any, thrown when setting `isTorchOn`
    @Published public var error: Error?

    /// get/set this value to check or change the torch state
    public var isTorchOn: Bool {
        get { _isTorchOn }
        set {
            if newValue != isTorchOn {
                do {
                    try setTorchMode(mode: newValue ? .on : .off)
                    error = nil
                } catch {
                    self.error = error
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// Does the work of changing torch state - throws any errors
    public func setTorchMode(mode: AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode) throws {
        guard let torch else { throw TorchControlError.noVideoDevice }
        guard torch.hasTorch else { throw TorchControlError.noTorch }
        try torch.lockForConfiguration()
        defer { torch.unlockForConfiguration() }
        guard torch.isTorchModeSupported(mode) else { throw TorchControlError.modeNotSupported }
        if mode == .on {
            try torch.setTorchModeOn(level: AVCaptureDevice.maxAvailableTorchLevel)
        } else {
            torch.torchMode = .off
        }
    }

    private var _isTorchOn: Bool = false { willSet { objectWillChange.send() }}
    private let torch: AVCaptureDevice? = .default(for: .video)
    private var torchModeObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    init() {
        guard let device = torch else { return }
        torchModeObservation = device.observe(\.isTorchActive, options: [.initial, .new]) { device, change in
            self._isTorchOn = device.torchMode == .on
        }
    }

    deinit {
        torchModeObservation?.invalidate()
        torchModeObservation = nil
    }
}

/// Some custom errors that can be thrown by `setTorchMode`
enum TorchControlError: Error {
    case noVideoDevice
    case noTorch
    case modeNotSupported
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```