# AVCapture​Photo​Output isFlashScene Key-Value-Observing

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, key-value-coding, avcapturephotosettings

I am following Apple's latest sample code ***AVCam Swift***, which is updated to use **AVCapture​Photo​Output**.

> var isFlashScene: Bool { get }
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether the scene currently being previewed
>   by the camera warrants use of the flash. This property’s value changes
>   depending on the scene currently visible to the camera. For example,
>   you might use this property to highlight the flash control in your
>   app’s camera UI, indicating to the user that the scene is dark enough
>   that enabling the flash might be desirable. If the photo capture
>   output’s supportedFlashModes value is off, this property’s value is
>   always false. This property supports Key-value observing.

I am trying to Key-value observe this so when Auto Flash Mode indicates that this is a scene that flash will fire (Just like the stock iOS Camera App), So I can change the UI, just like the documentation notes.

So I set it up like this:

```
private let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

private var FlashSceneContext = 0

self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "photoOutput.isFlashScene", options: .new, context: &FlashSceneContext)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
  if context == & FlashSceneContext {
     print ("Flash Scene Changed")
  }
}
```

Above never shows a change.  Even if I put a log in to check

```
print (self.photoOutput.isFlashScene)
```

This comes out as False all the time though out the app.

I also tried :

```
self.photoOutput.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "isFlashScene", options: .new, context: &FlashSceneContext)
```

.... still no change is Flash Scene, it's stuck on False.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285118/ios-check-if-torch-is-on) thread can help you, I hope.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing there..but looks like the proper way to add the observer is: self.photoOutput.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "isFlashScene", options: .new, context: &FlashSceneContext)

Comment: This seems to be a bug with isFlashScene.

Answer (score 5):

```
self.photoOutput.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "isFlashScene", options: .new, context: &FlashSceneContext)
```

Above was the proper way to setup the KVO.

photoSettingsForSceneMonitoring has to be implemented:

```
let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
photoSettings.flashMode = .auto
photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
self.photoOutput.photoSettingsForSceneMonitoring = photoSettings
```

Works!